# react native - change prop state depending on number of buttons selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using a nightlight button library: [react-native-selectmultiple-button](https://github.com/danceyoung/react-native-selectmultiple-button.git)
In this library there is a prop `selected`

Description: `Type:Boolean. Default is false. The selected prop determines whether the button is selected and highlighted`

Is there a way I can change the state of "selected" prop, depending on number of buttons selected?

For example, if I select more than 5 buttons, I want other buttons to be unselectable.

```
    constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
             numberOfbuttonsSelected:0
            }
          }

      {
         if(this.state.numberOfbuttonsSelected <5){
             <SelectMulipleButton 
                 selected={true}/>}
         else{<SelectMulipleButton 
                 selected={false}/>
               }
       }
```

The code above won't work any comments or advise would be really appreciated :)

This is the new code:

```
<View style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row',backgroundColor:'gray',paddingTop:10,paddingLeft:6,paddingRight:0,borderColor:'white', borderWidth:1}}>
          {
            multipleData.map(
              (interest) =>
                <SelectMultipleButton
                  key={interest}
                  buttonViewStyle={{
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    height: 40,
                    width: 110,
                  }}
                  textStyle={{
                    fontSize: 15,
                  }}
                  highLightStyle={{
                    borderColor: 'white',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    textColor: 'white',
                    borderTintColor: 'white',
                    backgroundTintColor: '#6AAAC6',
                    textTintColor: 'white',
                  }}
                  multiple={true}
                  value={interest}
                  selected={this.state.multipleSelectedData.includes(interest)}
          singleTap={valueTap => this.trackSelection(valueTap)} />
              )
          }
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: How are you selecting a button? On user interaction or programmatically? If it is on user interaction, you could use the `singleTap` prop to disable tapping on an unselected button depending on whether `numberOfButtonsSelected === 5`. You would also need to change the `numberOfButtonsSelected` every time you select or deselect a button.

Comment: @IshitaSinha thank you very much for the comment. I am selecting a button on user interaction. I am very new to react native and It would be very helpful if you could show me an simple example code.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please see if that works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay in replying. Please see my example component below. I have included explanations in comments inline in the code. Please reach out if you need further help.

```
export class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numberOfbuttonsSelected: 0,
      multipleSelectedData: []
    };
  }

  //This method is what you mainly need
  trackSelection = value => {
    if (!this.state.multipleSelectedData.includes(value)) { //This checks if the value already exists in the checked buttons list
      if (this.state.numberOfbuttonsSelected < 5) { //Here we check if the number of selected buttons has exceeded the specified number
        this.state.multipleSelectedData.push(value);
        this.setState({
          numberOfbuttonsSelected: this.state.numberOfbuttonsSelected + 1
        });
      } //else do nothing. Effectively, we are disabling the click on the button.
    } else { //we are simply toggling the selection here
      this.state.multipleSelectedData.splice(
        this.state.multipleSelectedData.indexOf(value), 1
      );
      this.setState({
        numberOfbuttonsSelected: this.state.numberOfbuttonsSelected - 1
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      //Customize your render function. I just included one button as an example.
      <View>
        <SelectMultipleButton
          multiple={true}
          value={interest} //"interest" is just an example value. Change it according to your requirements for each button.
          selected={this.state.multipleSelectedData.includes(interest)}
          singleTap={valueTap => this.trackSelection(valueTap)} //valueTap is supposed to be the "value" prop's value for each 
                //button according to the lib's documentation, but if you're not comfortable using valueTap, you can 
                //simply pass "interest" (or your own custom value for the particular button) into the trackSelection() method
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I went through the code in the lib and the `onPress` function in the `SelectMultipleButton` component is why your multiple selection still works:

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      if (this.props.multiple) {
        this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected })
        this.props.singleTap(this.props.value)
      } else {
        if (!this.state.selected) {
          this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected })
          this.props.singleTap(this.props.value)
        }
      }

    }
    }>
```

I know it's not a good idea to modify library files, but in this case, instead of using the whole lib, you can copy over [this](https://github.com/danceyoung/react-native-selectmultiple-button/blob/master/libraries/SelectMultipleButton.js) file to your project (don't remove the author credit at the top of this file) and add a prop `selectable` to it and modify the `onPress` thus:

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onPress={() => {
      if (this.props.multiple) {
        if(this.props.selectable) {
           this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected })
           this.props.singleTap(this.props.value)
         }
      } else {
        if (!this.state.selected) {
          this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected })
          this.props.singleTap(this.props.value)
        }
      }

    }
    }>
```

Pass the prop thus:

```
<SelectMultipleButton
          multiple={true}
          value={interest} 
          selectable={this.state.multipleSelectedData.includes(interest) || this.state.numberOfbuttonsSelected < 5}
          selected={this.state.multipleSelectedData.includes(interest)}
          singleTap={valueTap => this.trackSelection(valueTap)} 
        />
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the qualitative code and the comments It really means a lot :). I get what you are trying to say. But have you run this code?  I ran it and there is no error but  still I am able to select more than 5 buttons.

Comment: No, I haven't run the code because then I'll have to add the lib's dependency to a project and stuff. Can you put a breakpoint and check if the value of `this.state.numberOfbuttonsSelected` is changing or not? Are selected buttons getting deselected if you tap on them? Did you replace `interest` for your buttons to specific values? Also, try making `multiple={false}` and see if that helps. I have never used this lib before, but have made custom checkable buttons...so I can't be 100% sure how the lib works...

Comment: I edit my code. selected buttons are getting deselected when I tap it. I'll try working on it! Anyway thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Okay. Try debugging the `trackSelection` method and that should get you somewhere. :)

Comment: OMG thanks so much it works perfectly! I learned a lot from you. You're the best! :)

Comment: One issue I had was that `this.state.multipleSelectedData.splice(this.state.multipleSelectedData.indexOf(value)` would deselect the buttons corresponding to number of `value` so I assigned to just delete 1 index by `this.state.multipleSelectedData.splice(this.state.multipleSelectedData.indexOf(value), 1` :)

Comment: Cool. I'll add that to the answer so that others who face this may get this in the answer itself. I'm so glad I could help. :)